# Executing third party JavaScript snippets on impression

Tags: javascript

Impression trackers are commonly URLs that you can hit by using the `new Image().src` method or something similar. I've only ever seen pixels or PHP scripts get hit in these URLs.

What happens when a third party wants a JavaScript code snippet to execute? Like the following

```
<script src="http://their.special/javascript.file.js"></script>
<script>
    aFunctionThatExistsInThatSpecialFile();
    if(someFlagSetInThatFile) {
        someObjectInThatFile.setSomeProperty();
    }
    someOtherFunction();
</script>
```

Or it could look like

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('someID');
//... more JavaScript
```

The snippet could do whatever it wants like write out a cookie or something.

You can't load this as the source of an `img`. You shouldn't do a `document.write` because the impression event could fire after page load. A `document.write` could wipe the whole page.

So how do you use JavaScript to support this kind of impression tracker?

Comment: So I'd have to append a new script tag to the document?

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're talking about now. The problem isn't that the tag doesn't work. My problem is that this is some random third party JavaScript snippet (it doesn't necessarily even look like what's in my example) and I'd like to execute it on the impression event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at something like AdWords, you'd usually see something like:

```
<script src="//google.com/something/something.js"></script>
<script>
    account_name = "name";
    dollar_value = 37.05;
    fire_adWords_tracking();
</script>
```

That isn't really what it looks like at all.
But it is what it does -- basically.

These days, however, more programs are doing things like (consider GA):

```
var tracker = tracker || []; // if tracker doesn't exist, make it an array
tracker.push(["account", "12345H"],
             ["amount", "37.05"],
             ["product_name", "thingy"]);
```

And then at the bottom of the page, loading a script which will look for `tracker` and make an image to track all of the data:

```
(function () {
    var s = document.createElement("script"),
        parent = document.getElementsById("script")[0].parentNode,
        src = "//google.com/wherever.js";
    s.src = src;
    parent.appendChild(s);
}());
```

Whenever it loads, it will go through the array of stuff that was handed to it, and put it together one by one.

If you're talking about firing it on "Impression", then you (or your company's stakeholders -- marketing or IT, or a higher-up in Analytics) will have to define what "Impression" means to them.

For a lot of people, just having it on the bottom of the page, so that it fires when the page loads (ie: an "impression" of the page), is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<script src="http://their.special/javascript.file.js"></script>
<script>
    aFunctionThatExistsInThatSpecialFile();
    if(someFlagSetInThatFile) {
        someObjectInThatFile.setSomeProperty();
    }
    someOtherFunction();
</script>
```

Executing code inside of a `<script>` tag that has a `src` attribute in not allowed in HTML5, and may execute in some browsers, but is very unreliable and highly discouraged.

Comment: Oh, I understand what Musa was talking about now. I just mis-wrote the script tag. The problem isn't that the tag is failing. My problem is that I don't know how to execute this tag on the impression event.